# iOS accessibility on Alert: how to restrict focus within the alert?

Tags: ios, accessibility, uialertcontroller

Is it possible to restrict accessibility focus to within the alert view (ie. `UIAlertController`)? Swiping would not navigate to outside of the alert but user can tap somewhere outside, is this a designed behaviour (that normal user could see things outside so accessibility users should also be able to "see" them)?

Thanks!

Comment: I just tested this in my app. Using UIAlertController to present an alert results in the expected behavior where you cannot focus elements underneath the alert using VoiceOver. You’re seeing different behavior?

Comment: @Joey yes I could swipe and move the focus to things underneath the alert, I'm using `UIAlertController` as well and set its `accessibilityViewIsModal` to true.

Comment: What iOS version are you using? Do you see that same behavior with a brand new project that simply presents an alert?

Comment: @Joey iOS 11.3, existing project with complicated UI - maybe this is the reason, thanks for the information anyway!

Comment: @Joey BTW, if you create a new project and **only** present an alert, that might work, my situation is an existing project with tab bar and different view controllers, in your case, the voice over focus box may not have another place to move to?

Comment: Huh I’m unable to focus the tab bar or anything other than the alert elements. I would try to recreate the issue in a sample app and file a bug report at bugreport.apple.com.